# Add "Login With Facebook" or other custom button to UIAlertController or UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I would like to create a custom UIAlertController or UIAlertview that has the user-familiar "login with Facebook" button centered in a custom subview, and a cancel button. Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

[Similar Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02heL.png)

Comment: add screeenshot...what you want

Comment: if you want to do this you need to move on thirdparty or else create a custom UIView and add your wish whatever you want

Comment: you cant add facebook login button onto alertview. You have to make custom alertview for that!!!

Comment: Yes, I would like to make a custom alert view. I added an image that is similar to what I am looking for

Comment: I want to do the same thing...

Answer (score 3):

-For this you can use this type of popup Alert view

I used KGModal Library [here is link](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal) this library gives you exactly as you are looking for

It library gives access to manipulate view of popup UI and Tapoutside to close etc.